# Is LXDE in 12.04 LTS or not?

Tags: lubuntu, ubuntu-minimal

this question isn't more of a help me question, its just that I'm curious and it affects my computer. i installed the powerpc version of ubuntu minimal on my ibook g4 and i was planning on putting lubuntu on it through sudo tasksel, but i remembered that the 12.04 lubuntu isnt lts, so my question is, is if i install lxde through the ubuntu minimal installer, will it be lts or will it be pretty much a lubuntu install? thank you for your responses

Answer (score 2):

Lubuntu 12.04 is not an LTS, so all related packages are not LTS either, insculding LXDE. Needless to say, if you install just LXDE, it won't be Lubuntu, but rather, ...just LXDE.

You might be interested in Xubuntu though, which, in 12.04, is supported for 3 years (till April 2015), along with XFCE and related packages.